# Evaluating $\int_1^e\left\{\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{2x}-\left(\frac{e}{x}\right)^x\right\}\ln x\;dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> How to evaluate this integral?
> $$\int_1^e\left\{\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{2x}-\left(\frac{e}{x}\right)^x\right\}\ln x\;dx$$

I am trying this question by substituting $\frac{x}{e} =t$, and then $\frac{e}{x}$ will be $\frac{1}{t}$. So I am getting the integral to be
$$\int\left(t^{2x} -\frac{1}{t^x}\right)(1+\ln t)e\;dt$$ But how to approach further?

Answer (score 10):

Use the substitution $$t := \left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x$$
so that
$$\log t = x \log x - x\log e$$
and
$$\frac{dt}{t} = (x\cdot \frac1 x  + \log x - \log e)\, dx = \log x\, dx$$
This gives
$$\int_1^e\left\{\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{2x}-\left(\frac{e}{x}\right)^x\right\}\log x\, dx = \int_{1/e}^1 \left(t^2 - \frac1 t\right)\, \frac{dt}{t}$$
I believe you can take it from here!